# Questions related to Visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I am working on a project to implement guided selling feature by using visual workflow. I have couple of questions related to visual workflow with respect to requirements:

Q1) In order to improve look & feel from UI point of view, is it possible to embed VF pages (with custom fields) in your visual flow and after filling information with respect the screens populate and work with respect to visual workflow?
(I got to know through a friend that if VF page is embedded in VWF then user will be taken out from the flow and will experience VF page functionality, means the flow the will be broken and won't be saved)

Q2) Second requirement is that if I have selected a skip option for giving basic contact information, can I make the fields (First Name, Last Name and Email) not editable means not required?

Q3) I know through flow I can send emails but is it possible to attach any pdf file for example of quote via using flow? (Each time different quote with respect to the opportunity line items)

Please help me in meeting these requirements (any solution will be accepted)

Thanks//Ahsan -